# Copy and paste text with buttons

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I want to know what code I have to write under and IB action button so that when i click the button that is called copy, it will copy the text in a specified text view, and then when you click paste it will paste some text in a specified text view.

I can't find anything on this.  Does anyone have some code or a link to a good tutorial?

Thanks

Comment: You'll certainly not find a read-to-be-pasted solution for something like this. You have to come up with your own solution and ask specific questions if you're stuck. Nobody will write the code for you. And also, why use custom copy and paste buttons, when iOS has built in controls for that ([Cut, Copy & Paste](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/UsingCopy,Cut,andPasteOperations/UsingCopy,Cut,andPasteOperations.html))?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Look into [`UIPasteboard` Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIPasteboard_Class/Reference.html).

### Set

```
-(IBAction)copyText
{
    [[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] setString:myTextView.text];
}
```

### Get

```
myTextView2.text = [[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] string];
```