# paste text by code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Copy and paste text with buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150586/copy-and-paste-text-with-buttons)

I want to make past from the clipboard by code with out toggling the screen in iPhone , Any one have any idea ?

I want to make these operation by code not like these.

[image]

Um asking if these is possible or um accessing the iOS in that case ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150586/copy-and-paste-text-with-buttons?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

`[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard]` provides you an instance of [`UIPasteboard`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPasteboard_Class/Reference.html) which repents the users current clipboard content. Use it like

```
- (IBAction)pasteButtonPressed {
    self.myTextView.text = [[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] string];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`UIResponderStandardEditActions`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponderStandardEditActions_Protocol/UIResponderStandardEditActions.html) informal protocol declares the `paste:` method that is designed for that purpose. `UITextView` (along with other `UIResponder` subclasses) conforms to this informal protocol and thus responds to this method.

This has the advantage of managing every aspect of the pasting operation, especially pasting the text at the position of the insertion point, or replacing the selected text if any, as with a classic paste operation.

---

Another solution is to insert the text contained in the `UIPasteboard` yourself in your text view. But be sure in that case to replace the `selectedTextRange` (selected text or insertion point) and not replace the whole content of the `UITextView`.

For this purpose, use the fact that **`UITextView` implements the `UITextInput` formal protocol**, which declares every method needed to handle objects that manage text input (like `UITextView`, `UITextField`, etc) **especially `replaceRange:withText:` and `selectedTextRange`**:

```
NSString* pasteboardText = [[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] string];
[self.myTextView replaceRange:self.myTextView.selectedTextRange withText:pasteboardText];
```